# Magento change key product attributes default value

Tags: magento-1.7, attributes, default

I'd like to speed up product creation in the way that i don't have to select fields that never change for my store every time i add product.

Fields that i need to have default value are:

```
Status - Enabled
Weight - Zero by default
Tax Class - Taxable Goods
Product In Websites - Main Website Store
Auto Select radio "Base Image, Small Image, Thumbnail" to image that has order 1.
```

When i go to attribute manager and edit e.g. "status" its set to be dropdown, but "Manage Options (values of your attribute)" field is empty and adding options there has no effect.

Is there extension or easy way i can edit this i don't mind editing core files.

Comment: What is about mass product import?

Answer (score 1):

As an option, you can create several products and then mass change attributes in bulk from the grid using "change attribute" action.

Comment: Great i did not know about this option thanks. However in this case its no help as the attributes in question are "required" so it wont let me submit product without selecting them.

Answer (score 0):

Create a installer and update above catalog   product eav attributes default value.It may be works...

Comment: Could you go in more details i know magneto only at user level.

Answer (score 0):

Run this query on your database:

```
UPDATE 
    eav_attribute
SET 
    default_value = 1
WHERE
    attribute_code = 'status' AND
    entity_type_id = (
                          SELECT entity_type_id
                          FROM eav_entity_type
                          WHERE entity_type_code = 'catalog_product'
                     )
```